# Is this a Arithmetic or Geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

$A_n = n^8+7$

Is the above equation an arithmetic or geometric progression?

I would answer neither, but I'm not to sure.

Comment: Does there exist a common ratio between one term and the next, and is that ratio fixed across all terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct; it is neither.

Observe that $A_1 = 8, A_2 = 263, A_3 = 6568$.  $A_2/A_1 \not= A_3/A_2$, so it is not geometric.  $A_2-A_1 \not= A_3-A_2$, so it is not arithmetic.